# c++ declare a byte array of data type which is stored in string

Tags: c++

I have a data type name stored in string .
With that string , can i declare a variable of that data type.

Example,

```
string s = 'int';
```

I want to create a byte array of `int` .

Is there any way to do it in C++?

Comment: No. Although that said, you might want to take a look at variants.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I will try that

Answer (score 2):

> With that string , can i declare a variable of that data type.

No. C++ is a statically typed language and character strings are not constant expressions.

However, you can declare a variable of type `int` and conditionally use it depending on the contents of the string:

```
int foo;
if(str == "int")
    // use foo here
```

As a sidenote: `'int'` is an invalid character literal; you probably meant `"int"` instead.

Comment: You could go one step further and use a union here.

Comment: @OMGtechy sure, and we could take another step and use variants that you already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

A recent version of boost::variant, std::regex and c++14 gives us:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <regex>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception>
#include <sstream>

struct variant_value
{
    static auto evaluate(const std::string& s)
    {
        static const std::regex syntax(R"regex((.*)\((.*)\))regex");
        std::smatch result;
        if (std::regex_match(s, result, syntax))
        {

            if (result[1].str() == "int")
            {
                return variant_type(int(std::stoi(result[2].str())));
            }
            if (result[1].str() == "string")
            {
                std::stringstream ss(result[2].str());
                std::string rs;
                ss >> std::quoted(rs, '\'');
                return variant_type(rs);
            }
            if (result[1].str() == "float" || result[1].str() == "double")
            {
                return variant_type(std::stod(result[2].str()));
            }
        }
        throw std::invalid_argument(s);
    }

    variant_value(const std::string& s)
    : _vnt(evaluate(s))
    {}

    template<class F>
    decltype(auto) visit(F&& f) {
        return boost::apply_visitor(std::forward<F>(f), _vnt);
    }

    using variant_type = boost::variant<std::string, int, double>;



    variant_type _vnt;
};

// now test
int main()
{
    auto a = variant_value("string('hello world')");
    auto b = variant_value("int(10)");
    auto c = variant_value("float(6.43)");

    auto print = [](const auto& x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; };

    a.visit(print);
    b.visit(print);
    c.visit(print);

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
hello world
10
6.43
```